# Eclipse Android NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

When I try to run my project in the emulator it suddenly closes. Can you please have a look at my code and see what the problem might be?

---

### Main Activity

```
package com.college.profileaccount;


import com.college.profileaccount.adapter.PagerAdapter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter pAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(pAdapter);
}
}
```

---

### activity_main

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android.id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">    
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

---

### LOGCAT

```
10-26 20:17:23.936: D/dalvikvm(2631): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 92K, 6% free 2953K/3128K, paused 33ms, total 36ms
10-26 20:17:23.936: I/dalvikvm-heap(2631): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.566MB for 635812-byte allocation
10-26 20:17:23.976: D/dalvikvm(2631): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3571K/3752K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
10-26 20:17:24.046: D/AndroidRuntime(2631): Shutting down VM
10-26 20:17:24.046: W/dalvikvm(2631): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a93ba8)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): Process: com.college.profileaccount, PID: 2631
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.college.profileaccount/com.college.profileaccount.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.college.profileaccount.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-26 20:17:24.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     ... 11 more
10-26 20:17:27.496: I/Process(2631): Sending signal. PID: 2631 SIG: 9
10-26 20:22:45.746: D/dalvikvm(2680): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 5% free 2953K/3088K, paused 30ms, total 33ms
10-26 20:22:45.746: I/dalvikvm-heap(2680): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.566MB for 635812-byte allocation
10-26 20:22:45.776: D/dalvikvm(2680): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3571K/3712K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
10-26 20:22:45.886: D/AndroidRuntime(2680): Shutting down VM
10-26 20:22:45.886: W/dalvikvm(2680): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a93ba8)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680): Process: com.college.profileaccount, PID: 2680
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.college.profileaccount/com.college.profileaccount.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at com.college.profileaccount.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-26 20:22:45.896: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     ... 11 more
10-26 20:27:46.286: I/Process(2680): Sending signal. PID: 2680 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Whats on line 20 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: viewPager.setAdapter(pAdapter);

Answer (score 0):

It's `android:id="@+id/pager"` not `android.id="@+id/pager"`